# Order reporting module

Tags: orders, reports

I'm looking for a module that can create good reports for orders and order items: revenue, totals for payments and costs, total items, missing values, per year or month, per shop, etc. Which modules can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Aheadworks made a module that describes what you're searching for:

http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/advanced-reports.html

Haven't heard any bad reviews about it, so you could always give it a try.

Comment: Yeah I've seen that module, but I don't see how it can create reports about costs vs income.